# bootstrap modal ajax call as callback

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal which holds a form and from holds a select option field and I would like to populate this with help of ajax on modal('show')

So I have been trying the following but on first click won't fire and after each click the request are duplicated

```
    $('#addNew').modal('show');
    $('#addNew').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
           //ajax call to populate select option
           var url = ajaxurl + '?action=getCategories';                            
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not changing the scenario?

```
 function showAddNewModal(){
    //ajax call to populate select option
       var url = ajaxurl + '?action=getCategories';                            
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
             //populate select option here
             $('#addNew').modal('show');
        }
    });
   }
```

Also when you are using POST method , you should change your request to :

```
$.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:{"action":"getCategories"},
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                 //populate select option here
                 $('#addNew').modal('show');
            }
      });
```